# Prove existence of a point in continuous function

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function in $\left [ 0,1 \right ]$ so that for every $x\in \left [ 0,1 \right ]$ there is $f(x)\in \left [ 0,1 \right ]$.

Prove that there such a point $x_0\in \left [ 0,1 \right ]$ so that $x_0 + f(x_0) = 1$

Could you please point me to the right direction with this question?
I Tried proving it using Stone–Weierstrass theorem and intermediate value theorem but didn't got anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Look at $g(x)=x+f(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $g(x) := x + f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and has $g(0) = f(0) \le 1$ and $g(1) = 1 + f(1) \ge 1$. Hence, by the intermediate value theorem, $g(x_0) = 1$ for some $x_0 \in [0,1]$, i.e., $x_0 + f(x_0) = 1$ for some $x_0 \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Typo: You mean $g(x_0)=1$, and your proof is nicer than mine, even if it is the same idea :) +1

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider $g(x):=1-f(x)-x$. Then $g:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous function. Use the Intermediate Value Theorem to prove that $g$ has a zero $x_0$, i.e. $g(x_0)=0$. Then this $x_0$ satisfies $1-f(x_0)-x_0=0$ and hence $1=f(x_0)+x_0$.